# An action failed. No dependent actions succeeded

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am getting below error and below are the flow steps and i got to increment the noofassignments field whenever the status is changed as Active,Kindly help

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

update item, I use the below expression to increment the counter for the Noofassignments field

[image]

Comment: Can you please go back to a failed run of your flow and click the "Update Item" step inside "Yes". That should provide more information about why that step is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#empty, `empty` function can't be used on types other than String, Array, or Object. Though numbers are typed as Float, Integer or any number types which is also an object in dotnet, the term "Object" here refers to an entirely JSON object. So, that's probably the reason why it's error.

So you might need to change your expression to `if(equals(items('Apply_to_each')?['Noofassignments'],null),1,add(items('Apply_to_each')?['Noofassignments'],1))`.

Hope that helps.